# 2 editors on Ubuntu, Gedit and Kwrite?

Tags: text-editor

I wanted to know if it's possible to have 2 text editor on Ubuntu. I have gedit already installed but I wanna experiment with Krite too.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can install Kwrite from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: You might find that the needed packages to install it in Ubuntu offputting though.

Comment: @forestpiskie yeah, installing KDE packages while mainly using GNOME can result in a huge mess.